# How to extract some particular text from a value in a key present in a Python dictionary (JSON)

Tags: python, json, dictionary, key-value, data-extraction

I have this JSON data that I need to go through to extract all the data present in customfield_20340 that contains Crucible links. My task is to extract **only** the Crucible links present as a value in a given key. When I extract the Crucible links, I do not want any other characters or text.
For example, I do not want the text  and so on, just the individual links.
At the moment, I am able to extract the entire content present in customfield_20340.

How would y'all solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were able to extract the full field, you just have to split it and keep what starts with `http`:

```
links = [i for i in data['fields']['customfield_20340'].split() if i.startswith('http')]
```

Comment: Ah yes, the startswith function. This worked, thank you!
I have marked it as the accepted answer.